# mysql table structure with multiple variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a script which will counts the number of ticket as per as different conditions and store the count in a summary table. I am unable to understand how to structure my table since there will be more than 1 variables.

[image]

The script will run every week and with each execution a new week will be added. Once the new month starts and scripts execute, a new month will be added and once new year starts a new year will be added. So in a nutshell I have columns which are also variables. Not sure how to handle it and structure my db.

Comment: which is the minimum time range to storage, one week? Btw, you can handle it with analysis services.

Comment: STORE the data with a date value.  DISPLAY the data using a pivot on year/month (and week if necessary)  How you store your data is not always how you need to display the data.

Comment: You mean to say the count_date?
service1: 72_may16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have columns Date Service Count.

Like so.

```
Date            Service      Count
16 May 2016     Service1     35
```

Then when you go to display them in the report pivot them as you want. Probably better to make date an INT and either an auto number PK or composite PK of Date and Service.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong approach.  Do not splay an array across columns.  Instead have *rows* for the data.  This lets you trivially "add" another month.

For displaying, well that is an application problem, no a MySQL problem.  Sure, you can write specialized queries to "pivot" the data from rows to columns, but it is messy.